# MySQL port showing close after changing bind-address to server's private address

Tags: mysql, database-replication, droplet, remote-mysql

I am using Digital Ocean's droplet I want to access my database though my workbench. Earlier I was using Google's compute engine with same settings like changing bind-address to server's private-ip and then creating user with same ip as a host. Example

my.cnf

```
port = 3306
bind-address = 10.223.0.1
```

mysql user

```
CREATE USER 'adam'@'10.223.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'abc@123';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'adam'@'10.223.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I was able to access this user on my local machine with the use of server's external IP.

But now if I update bind-address with my private IP and check with external port checker tool. it tells me that port 3306 is closed and if I change to 0.0.0.0 than port shows open and I am able to access. But the thing is, I am adding updating private ip as I want to replicate my database to another server. how I can solve this.

Ufw is allowed for 3306 ipv4 ipv6 and droplet firewall have inbound rules for 3306 too

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I created SSH connection tunnel to connect mysql remotely and kept my bind-address as server's private IP.